# Abbreviate Author's Name When Using Bibtex?

Tags: hyperref

I'm using bibtex to cite a few organizations. However, I was wondering if I can use abbreviated names when I'm citing in a sentence, but show the full organization name in my reference section?

For example, I'm trying to write:
c (2021) COVID-19 is... instead of World Health Organization (2021). I'm using:

```
According to WHO \cite{who21covid} COVID-19 is...
```

Comment: It's not clear from your posting whether you use bibtex -- as would be indicated from the title and first sentence of the posting -- or biblatex -- one of two tags you've set. Please clarify.

Comment: Editted to remove biblatex tag. I didn't know bibtex (what im using) and biblatex are different.

Comment: Thanks for providing this clarification. Please address two more questions. First, which bibliography style do you employ? Second, do you use a citation management package such as `natbib` or `apacite`?

Comment: I'm using apa style (\bibliographystyle{apa}) and natbib (\usepackage{natbib})

Answer (score 2):

This is part of the standard authoryear type styles in `biblatex` when using the `shortauthor` field:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{filecontents}[force]{\jobname.bib}
  @book{test,
    author    = {National Institute of Mental Health},
    shortauthor = {NIMH},
    title     = {Some Title},
    year      = {2003}
  }
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage{bibentry}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

\cite{test}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Since you employ the `natbib` citation management package with a bibliography style that produces authoryear-style citation call-outs, I suggest you employ citation aliasing mechanism along the following lines, where I've defined "WHO" as a citation alias for an entry with key `who:2021`. (You're obviously free to choose a different abbreviation/acronym.) Then, just use `\citetalias{who:2021}` instead of `\citet{who:2021}`.

[image]

Note that since "World Health Organization" in an example of a "corporate" author, it's necessary to write `author  = {{World Health Organization}},` in order to prevent BibTeX from interpreting the `author` field as containing a single author with last name "Organization" and given names "World" and "Health".

```
\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class

% create a sample bib file 'on the fly':
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{mybib.bib}
@misc{who:2021,
   author  = {{World Health Organization}},
   year    = 2021,
   title   = {Covid-19},
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[authoryear,round]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\defcitealias{who:2021}{WHO}

% optional:
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[colorlinks,allcolors=blue]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\noindent
According to \citet{who:2021} (hereafter: \citetalias{who:2021}), \dots
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```