# Abbreviating in-text citation with link to the reference section and without space

Tags: natbib

How can I produce author-year citations in the format `[LastNameInitials+Year]` in LaTeX using the natbib package or any other package?

MWE:

```
@article{Smith_Jones_2010,
  author  = {A. Smith and B. Jones},
  title   = {A paper by Smith and Jones},
  journal = {Journal of Important Research},
  volume  = {10},
  pages   = {1--10},
  year    = {2010},
}
```

Assuming that you have a .bib file named mybibfile.bib with an entry for Smith_Jones_2010

Here's an example document that uses the natbib package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{natbib}

\begin{document}

According to \citeauthor{Smith_Jones_2010} [\citeyear{Smith_Jones_2010}],...

\bibliographystyle{abbrvnat}
\bibliography{mybibfile}

\end{document}
```

I want the output to look like `[J2010]`. If there are multiple authors, say Smith Jones and James Smith, I want the output to be `[JS2010]`.

I have tried various things and I have looked at various posts like [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/655781/abbreviate-authors-name-when-using-bibtex), [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/98567/how-to-abbreviate-authors-firstname-in-bibliography) and [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/502552/how-to-include-shortauthor-abbreviations-and-urldate-to-a-author-year-bibliograp).

[The first link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/655781/abbreviate-authors-name-when-using-bibtex) is the closest that I have gotten. The issue is that, first there is a space between last name initials and the year, and secondly, the initials are not linked to the reference, only the year is linked.

In text citation looks like: `[J 2010]`

Comment: Have you tried the `alpha` bibliography style?

Comment: Not the exact thing that I am looking for, but much better and close to what I wanted. This will do it for me :)  Thanks!